# redirecting pages in yii afterlogin

Tags: php, redirect, yii

This is my Sitecontroller.php Im trying to redirect the user after login to a static website that only shows a simple hello. I'm having trouble redirecting my this to my aindex.php

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;
    Yii::app()->session['username'] = 'seslog';
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')      
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))                      
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

            if($model->validate() && $model->login()){      

                $this->redirect(array('site/aindex'));//i can't redirect this

            }
    }

    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));                      
}
```

here is my aindex.php file

```
<?php
   echo "Hello ";
?>
```

Comment: do a debug and check if the `$this->redirect(array(..... ` can be reached!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'array' But the value you are sending is a specific URL, not an array.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

Just use :-  $this->redirect('site/aindex');